# How to show image in img tag selected from gallery on phonegap?

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

```
 <script>
        function text()
        {
                            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
                            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
                            {

                                                   quality: 50,
                                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                            });


        }
    function onSuccess(imageData)
    {
        alert('success image date ='+imageData);
        document.getElementById('myImage').src=imageData;
    }
    function onFail(message)
    {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

When i am getting path of the image from **File_Uri** but using this url can't get the image .

That Path is like `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3a39762`

```
 <img id"myImage" alt="choosed images" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your HTML `<img>` tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh where? kindly point out that

Comment: @MarcusMüller i got the syntax from here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Read closely. your `id` is missing an `=`

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes correct bro thanks ..

Comment: I'd advise you to use base64 to overcome this URI to URL issue. otherwise you can run a block wise search to get the device path of that URI.